# Determining duplicates when original has no accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

How should the duplicates be determined when the original has no accepted answer?

I just stumbled over a case like that:

- 19 Feb 2015 [GRASS 7.1 (dev.) i.landsat.toar error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/135982/53268) - original question with one  answer (4 upvotes) but that has not been accepted
- 9 Oct 2015 [i.landsat.toar not working and returning error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/165961/53268) - question with an accepted answer which has been made a duplicate of [GRASS 7.1 (dev.) i.landsat.toar error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/135982/53268)
- 13 Jan 2016 https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/176588/53268 - new question with no answers which has been made a duplicate of [GRASS 7.1 (dev.) i.landsat.toar error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/135982/53268)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer assumes that the three questions that you have cited all represent the same issue and that there is no debate about whether they should be duplicates.  Consequently, I think your question is really about whether the question with an accepted answer should be the one that the others are made a duplicate of.

The way the duplicates are currently set is, I think, correct because the use of the accept button in this instance merely indicates an answer that helped the asker of the second question the most.

I suspect that your concern is that the community finding either the first or third question in a search will be left unaware of an answer to the second question.

So that answers to the second question get due consideration by everyone finding any of the three questions what I think is needed is for the second question (and its answers) to be merged with the first.  This is something that you can flag for a moderator to do from either of those questions by using the Other option.

What you will need to do prior to that is to make sure that when someone comes into either the first or the second question and sees any of the answers from both together, that the answers will line up with either question.  This will need some careful editing.